# Inserting a signature in PDF document

Tags: pdf

I often see PDF letters that have a person's signature in it at the bottom. Is this functionality via certain tools? If so, which ones? (I'm on Windows 8)

For example, [see this letter](https://express.star-k.org/viewer/LOCViewer.aspx?id=YCNSENE7%5E%7C%5Etarget=inline):

[image]

I use PDF Architect 4 as my PDF editor but whenever I look up "insert signature" in the menus of this or other programs it usually gives me the digital signature option which seems a totally different task than inserting a "physical" signature.

What's the right way to do this? Or does one just scan a paper signature and insert a image manually in the PDF? I don't think this is the right workflow because the signatures in professional documents look very natural and not just a scan and paste job. (e.g. the background doesn't vary noticeably in the scanned area)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the PDF you have shown the most likely method is to scan a persons signature and then insert the image into the document. You would then be able to insert their signature into multiple documents, resizing as required.

This could be done whilst in an editor such as MS Word prior to PDF Conversion or afterwards is some of the PDF editors such as Adobe's paid version of Acrobat.

Digital signatures are cryptographic methods to prove that the PDF is from the person who it claims to be and that it has not been tampered with.

Answer (score 1):

> Or does one just scan a paper signature and insert a image manually in the PDF? I don't think this is the right workflow

To import a physical signature into a PDF document one can do the following:

- Create the signature with a [stylus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylus_(computing)) or [digital pen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_pen). The result would a be very natural signature with a clean (even transparent) background. It is even possible to make a [vector version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) of the signature with the method, so the signature scales when larger or smaller ones are needed.
- Scan the signature but after doing so, perform the background removal procedure on in it in a [raster graphics editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics_editor) such as Adobe Photoshop, GIMP, paint.net, etc. Background removal is in fact so easy that I am surprised why people don't do it. I don't want to advertise a specific website here, so please Google it yourself.

> digital signature option which seems a totally different task

You are totally right. The only similarity between a digital signature and a physical signature is their name. A digital signature is **not** a signature and does not serve the same purpose.

Comment: Ah! Never thought of the stylus option. That totally removes the background interference from the equation. Thanks!